# Why can't the Instagram story be viewed?

Tags: instagram

There are three Instagram accounts: A, B, C.

- A is public.
- A and B follow each other.
- C is freshly created, it doesn’t follow anyone and is not banned by anyone.

A posts a story.

- B can see that there is an unseen story by A (and can check it out).
- Unauthorised user can see that there is an unseen story by A (colourful circle around the avatar), but cannot open it (which is expected).
- C cannot see that there are any unseen stories by A (colourful circle disappears).

How is it possible?

My guess was that A shared the story with some of their 'close friends' (including B), so the unauthorised user can see 'there is something', but as soon as they log in as C, they can't see it anymore. But when I share some story with some close friends, an unauthorised user won't see the colourful circle at all.